# How to resolve NoSuchFieldError exception when testing Lucene 4.0

Tags: java, lucene

I want to test my own Analyzer. Following is test code from **Lucene in Action 2nd Edition, Code List 4.2, page 121**.

```
public class AnalyzerUtils {
    public static void displayTokens(Analyzer analyzer, String text) throws IOException {
        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("contents", new StringReader(text));
        displayTokens(tokenStream);
    }

    public static void displayTokens(TokenStream stream) throws IOException {
        CharTermAttribute term = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        while(stream.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(term.buffer()));
        }
    }
}
```

My customed Analyzer is:

```
 static class SimpleAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    static class SimpleFilter extends TokenFilter {
        protected SimpleFilter(TokenStream input) { super(input); }
        @Override
        public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException { return false; }
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, new SimpleFilter(tokenizer));
    }
}

static class FilteringAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    static class FilteringFilter extends FilteringTokenFilter {
        public FilteringFilter(TokenStream in) { super(in); }
        @Override
        protected boolean accept() throws IOException { return false; }
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, new FilteringFilter(tokenizer));
    }
}
```

Problem is if I run `AnalyzerUtils.displayTokens(new SimpleAnalyzer(), "美国 法国 中国");`, it is ok; however, running `AnalyzerUtils.displayTokens(new FilteringAnalyzer(), "美国 法国 中国");` I got this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LATEST
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter.<init>(FilteringTokenFilter.java:70)
    at cn.edu.nju.ws.miliqa.nlp.ner.index.NameEntityIndexing$FilteringFilter.<init>(NameEntityIndexing.java:62)
    at cn.edu.nju.ws.miliqa.nlp.ner.index.NameEntityIndexing$FilteringAnalyzer.createComponents(NameEntityIndexing.java:83)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:134)
    at cn.edu.nju.ws.miliqa.lucene.AnalyzerUtils.displayTokens(AnalyzerUtils.java:19)
```

The difference between to test case is the filter in analyzer extendes `TokenFilter` or `FilteringTokenFilter`. I have been working on it for three days, but still have no idea about it. What is the reason for this odd exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-how-to-solve-suchfielderror/) runtime exception means you have one class attempting to access a field on another class that doesn't exist. The offending class was [FilteringTokenFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.10.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/FilteringTokenFilter.java#FilteringTokenFilter.%3Cinit%3E%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version%2Cboolean%2Corg.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream%29).

Most likely, you have multiple versions of Lucene in your classpath.

You mention you are using 4.0 in the title, but [Version.LATEST](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.10.0/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.java#Version.0LATEST) (the field this exception is complaining is missing) was not introduced until Lucene 4.10.

That implies that perhaps you have a copy of FilteringTokenFilter.class in a Lucene 4.10+ jar file attempting to find the field "LATEST" in an older (4.0?) Version.class file.

Check you only have one copy of each "lucene-core" and "lucene-analyzers-common" jar files in your class path, and that they are both matching version numbers. If you are not sure, download them again to ensure you have matching versions.